# How to handle custom Namespaces in XSLT other than using extensions?

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xml-namespaces

I have the following xsml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gas-xml xmlns="http://gas-xml.de/3.2/gas-xml">
    <body>              
        <data> 
            <voplist object-id="someID" period="hour" values-per-period="1" >
                <vopset quantity="Vbus">
                    <vop i="0" state="">0</vop>
                    <vop i="1" state="">0</vop>
                    <vop i="2" state="">0</vop>
                </vopset>
            </voplist>
        </data>
    </body>
</gas-xml>
```

I try to transform it to another xml file with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <body>
            <timeseries dateformat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" freq="Hourly" valuealign="left">
                <xsl:for-each select="/body/data/voplist/vopset/vop">
                    <value>
                        <xsl:attribute name="time">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@i"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </timeseries>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But somehow the Namespace `<gas-xml xmlns="http://gas-xml.de/3.2/gas-xml">` doesn't let for-each to read through the xml file because when i delete the part `xmlns="http://gas-xml.de/3.2/gas-xml` from the namespace it works fine. I have used the Method with extensions but the system I am working with doesn't allow extensions. So I am looking for an another solution rather than using extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use namespace (**xmlns="http://gas-xml.de/3.2/gas-xml"**) as below in xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:a="http://gas-xml.de/3.2/gas-xml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="a"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <body>
            <timeseries dateformat="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ" freq="Hourly" valuealign="left">
                <xsl:for-each select="//a:body/a:data/a:voplist/a:vopset/a:vop">
                    <value>
                        <xsl:attribute name="time">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@i"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                    </value>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </timeseries>
        </body>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jxNakA4

Comment: Great, it works. Could you maybe explain also what the :a does? You give it a prefix and delete it right after that with exclude-result-prefix?

Comment: if there is no identifier in namespace in source xml than in xslt it need to call with a dummy identifier, if you don't pass dummy identifier for that namespace you can't be able to retrive xml element.